# On stochastic derivative: an apparent contradiction(?)

Tags: derivatives, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

If I understood it correctly, for any given stochastic process $Y_t$, generally depending upon position $x$ and time $t$, a function $f(Y_t,t)$ is said to be differentiable with respect to $Y_t$ if its derivative
$$\tag{1}\frac{\partial f(y,t)}{\partial y}$$
should exist for all possible realizations $y(x,t)$ of $Y_t$.
**Isn't this contradictory?** For suppose $f$ is the identity function. It's clearly everywhere differentiable, but the Wiener process, which can be seen as the identity function applied to it, is not.

Comment: The derivative is $1$, which is the constant function so it exists for all possible realizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The natural derivative in stochastic calculus is the **Malliavin Derivative.**
Take a look in these posts: [Wiki](https://www.bing.com/ck/a?!&&p=974cb52e97f34bd1JmltdHM9MTY3OTYxNjAwMCZpZ3VpZD0wODMzYTdjOC03ZWM4LTZkMDctMzM0My1iNTE2N2Y3YzZjYjImaW5zaWQ9NTE3MQ&ptn=3&hsh=3&fclid=0833a7c8-7ec8-6d07-3343-b5167f7c6cb2&psq=Malliavin%20derivative&u=a1aHR0cHM6Ly9lbi53aWtpcGVkaWEub3JnL3dpa2kvTWFsbGlhdmluX2Rlcml2YXRpdmU&ntb=1), [Malliavin derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2909420/malliavin-derivative-of-a-gaussian)

Let $\mathcal H$ be a separable Hilbert.  Let $W_t$ is the $1$-dimensional Wiener process. Consider
$$
F=f(W(h_1),W(h_2),\ldots,W(h_n)),\ h_1, h_2,\ldots,h_n\in\mathcal{H}, \, n\ge 1,
$$
where $f$ is a smooth function with their partial derivatives have polynomial growth.
We define Malliavin's  derivative  of $F$ as the random variable value:
$$
\displaystyle DF=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}(W(h_1), W(h_2),\ldots,W(h_n))h_k.
$$
It satisfies the following properties:

1. $\displaystyle D(FG)=FDG+GDF.$
2. $\displaystyle \mathbf{E}(\langle DF,h\rangle_{\mathcal{H}})=\mathbf{E}(FW(h))$
3. $\displaystyle \mathbf{E}(G\langle DF,h\rangle_{\mathcal{H}})=\mathbf{E}(-F\langle DG,h \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}+FGW(h))$